# Ошибка работы авторизации в yii2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2, debian, сессия, auth

Здравствуйте!
Использую стандартную авторизацию и регистрацию. После успешной авторизации рендрю главную страницу. Но если обновить страницу или перейти на другую в этом же проекте, то меня выбрасывает обратно на страницу авторизации. 
Причем так работает проект на одном компе, на втором все норм.
Думаю проблема в серваке и в сессии но найти конкретно не могу. Скажите, в чем проблема конкретно?

Comment: Домены одинаковые? Посмотрите что в конфиге сессий и кук у вас прописано. Авторизируйтесь и посмотрете на куки в испекторе. Обратите внимание на домен и время их жизни.